# How do I auto-indent a forest tree in the source?

Tags: forest

I often have to work with large collections of `forest` trees whose indentation in the source is collapsed, for example:

```
[A[B][C[D]]]
```

or

```
[A
[B]
[C
[D]
]
]
```

This is of course hardly readable as soon as the trees get more complicated. What I would like to have is

```
[A
  [B]
  [C
    [D]
  ]
]
```

I tried with `latexindent.pl`, which does the job but it also unindents the trees which are already well-formatted. Is there an alternative way to do it?

Comment: Hm, that is matter of you editor, isn't it?

Comment: Well, `latexindent.pl` is for example editor agnostic. So I am asking generally about postprocessing tools and/or plugins for e.g. Vim, Emacs and the like. Otherwise I will script it myself, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If `latexindent` does what you want, why don't you save the desired tree in a separate dummy tex file, format your source code with the script, and paste it in your working tex file? It's slightly over the top, but won't hurt much IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately AucTeX+Emacs doesn't support formatting of the source-code enclosed in `[` & `]` :( I would love to see this feature in AucTeX.

Comment: That is what I thought, but depending on the system and the editor, formatting is not kept by pasting, which is also the reason why most trees are not indented in the first place. The best solution would be a postprocessing tool, since it would bypass this problem.

Comment: I agree. It's a much needed feature. Not just for trees, but anything written in square brackets.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is very `forest`-centric, which is why I believe there aren't many solutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134524/discussion-between-niranjan-and-eslukas).

Comment: [Just for the records.](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2022-03/msg00004.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the generous efforts of the AucTeX developers this functionality has been developed in it post v13.1 (2022-03-16).

Discussion related to this can be found [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2022-03/msg00004.html).

In any emacs buffer with `latex-mode` enabled, one can evaluate the following commands to have the desired effect.

```el
(setq TeX-indent-open-delimiters "[")
(setq TeX-indent-close-delimiters "]")
```

You can add these lines to your init file (~/.emacs) to make this indentation turned on by default.

Comment: Excellent!! Thank you for pushing this, @Niranjan

Comment: @eslukas In fact thanks to you for raising this! :-)